# How to print two "pieces" next to each other?

Tags: c++, class

I have a class:

```
class Piece{

    public: 
        void print();

    private:
        string piece_name_;

        int top_;
        int right_;
        int lower_;
        int left_;

        string piece_;

};
```

it describes puzzlepiece, for example like this 
A/!
+␣!
C!

each side has a number (top, right...)

I made function to print this piece but i need a way to print two pieces next to each other
like this

/-␣HDA
!R!IEB
-/JFC

Does anyone have an idea how to approach this problem?

```
void Piece::print(){

    for(string::size_type i = 0; i < piece_.size(); ++i){
        cout << piece_.at(i);
        if(i == 2 or i == 5 or i == 8){
            cout << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The combined multi-piece sample would make a lot more sense if you used the same samples from your *single* piece print-outs.

Comment: How are the pieces supposed to fit with each other? Your examples of `A/!`, `!R!`, etc. just look like gibberish to me and its hard to see what you are trying to do.

Comment: Also, what are you trying to print out exactly? In your `print` method, you are printing out individual characters of some (assumed) string `piece_` that doesn't exist in your class. I assume this is supposed to be `piece` or `piece_name_`. If so, what format are these supposed to be in?

Comment: A/!
+␣!
C! gives the piece its appearance. nuumbers on top, right etc. tells what piece it fits together with. sorry for unclear representation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Separate concerns, conversion to string(or strings) should be separate from printing.  Then you could convert to string a number of pieces then print them how ever you like.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what the piece information like "A/!" represents, but you could print two pieces with a non-member function

```
void printTwoPieces(Piece a, Piece b) {
  a.print();
  b.print();
  cout << endl;
}
```

You would also need to replace the if statement in Piece::print() with `return;`, unless you need to output a newline only in specific cases. Then the problem hasn't been described with sufficient detail.

Comment: doesn't that print the other piece below the first? I need to print them next to eachother. A/! are characters that are just there to make pieces visually different from eachother

Comment: It doesn't print one below the other if you remove the cout << endl statement (along with the rest of the if statement) from the Piece::print().

Answer (score 0):

First, you can't do what I think you want to do, with `Piece::print` writing directly to `std::cout`. Start by writing a stream insertion operator like `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, Piece const&)`.

Then, you can format two pieces to strings which you control:

```
void format_pieces(Piece const &p1, Piece const &p2) {
  std::stringstream s1, s2;
  s1 << p1;
  s2 << p2;
```

and finally you can concatenate each line.